# How to pass an object as a parameter in a new method?

Tags: java

Ok... I now this is a silly question, but I am struggling with this.

```
public class University {

private List<Student> students;

public University() {
    this.student = new ArrayList();
}

public void loadFile(String fileStudents) throws  IOException {
    BufferedReader readStudents = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileStudents));
    while(true){
        String line = readStudents.readLine();
        if( line == null)
            break;
        String fields[] = line.split(":");

        Student e = new Student(Long.parseLong(fields[0]),fields[1], fields[2]);
        //System.out.println(e);
        students.add(e);
    }

}

public List<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
}

public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
    this.students = students;
}
```

I want to create a new method passing as a paramenter the object "e".
I want to return e.getNome();

Comment: What do you mean the object `e`? like `(Student e)`? just the name?

Comment: Nevermind i see now.. you named your Student object e sorry.

Comment: public String getNome(Student student) { return student.getNome();}

Comment: `public String getName(Student e) { return e.getNome(); }`

Comment: Yeah, I've create here: 
Student e = new Student(Long.parseLong(fields[0]),fields[1], fields[2]);

Now I want to call the method getName(); from my Student class using 'e'.

Comment: Oh well either in your student class just simply put.. `public String getName() { return //variable name here }` so then you can do `e.getName();` or just make a method inside your `University class` doing `public String getName(Student student) { return student.getName(); }`

Comment: public String getName(Student student) { return student.getName(); }

Comment: This worked, thank you both so much :D
Have a nice day.